Secondary transformer for Nest stat
What are the terminals for a secondary transformer wiring into a Nest thermostat?Hydronic system no C wire.
Thanks!!!

The block terminals in the backplate of the Nest. I have Y, C,W,G, R, OB terminals. I’m wiring the secondary transformer to C and OB, but get a message of no power. Thanks.

what do you mean when you ask What are the terminals ?

Everything that's 24 volt has a C connection somewhere -- but especially on older equipment it is often not clearly labeled as such. If you can bring us photos of the wiring diagram and the actual connections on the equipment we can probably help you sort it out. A secondary transformer might or might not be needed, but even if it is, we'll need to ensure it is connected with the hydronic system in the correct polarity/phasing.
